# Java Help. I need help debugging

Tags: java

This is my code:
http://codepad.org/vGrVJr59 
My problem is the added whitespace at the end. Please help. 
ERROR OUTPUT:
Whitespace differs; see green (missing whitespace) or red (extra whitespace) boxes above.
Tests aborted.

Complete the printTicTacToe method with char parameters `horizChar` and `vertChar` that prints a tic-tac-toe board with the characters as follows. End with newline. Ex: `printTicTacToe('~', '!')` prints:

```
x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
~~~~~
x!x!x
```

Hint: To ensure printing of characters, start your print statement as: System.out.println("" + horizChar ...).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoardPrinter {
    public static void printTicTacToe(char horizChar, char vertChar) {

        for(int i=1;i<4;i++){ 
            for(int j=1;j<4;j++){ 
                System.out.print("x");
                if(j<3){
                    System.out.print(vertChar);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
            if(i!=3){
                for(int j=1;j<6;j++){ 
                    System.out.print(horizChar);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        printTicTacToe('~', '!');
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include code and a description of the error in the question instead of linking to external resources.

Comment: The relevant code, and a clear explanation of the expected and actual result, must be in the question itself.

Comment: When you have a `void` method, using `return` is unnecessary. Your `import` statement isn't used as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know why your code gets an extra white space.
See, you made three `returns` by these code:

```
System.out.print("\n");
```

and then, you add another blank line by

```
System.out.println();
```

that's why you got the ERROR OUTPUT.
Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the print statement to before the closing if bracket like so

```
public class GameBoardPrinter
{
public static void printTicTacToe(char horizChar, char vertChar)
{
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("x");

            if(j < 3)
            {
                System.out.print(vertChar);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        if(i != 3)
        {

            for(int j = 1; j  <6; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(horizChar);
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    printTicTacToe('-', '|');
}
}
```

Comment: It worked! thank you, can you explain to me why the print statement had to be before the closing bracket?

Comment: @knmn No problem! It had to because it was executing every time it looped through, instead of only when it met the condition of `i != 3`  like you wanted to. Accepting the answer would be much appreciated as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameBoardPrinter {
    public static void printTicTacToe(char horizChar, char vertChar) {

        System.out.println("x" + vertChar + "x" + vertChar + "x" );
        System.out.println(horizChar + "" +horizChar + "" +horizChar + "" +horizChar+ "" +horizChar);
        System.out.println("x" + vertChar + "x" + vertChar + "x" );
        System.out.println(horizChar + "" +horizChar + "" +horizChar + "" +horizChar+ "" +horizChar);
        System.out.println("x" + vertChar + "x" + vertChar + "x" );
        return;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        printTicTacToe('~', '!');
        return;
    }
}
```